Does the spectrum of $T(1+T^*T)^{-1}$ contain a compactification of that of $T$?
Let $T$ be a densely defined closed operator in the Hilbert space $\mathcal H$.  Then $T^*T\ge0$, and $Q = T(1+T^*T)^{-1}$ has norm $\le1$ (Theorem 13.13 of Rudin's Functional Analysis).  Define the complex function $f(z) = z/(1+\lvert z\rvert^2)$.
Question:  Is it true that $f\bigl(\sigma(T)\bigr) \subseteq \sigma(Q)$?
If $T$ is normal, then $Q = f(T)$ and by the spectral mapping theorem $\sigma(Q)$ is the closure of $f\bigl(\sigma(T)\bigr)$, so the answer is affirmative in this case.  Note however that we cannot expect equality of the closures in general, for instance when $T$ has empty spectrum.

This is not true even when $T$ is bounded. For example, let $T = 2S$ where $S$ is the right-shift operator on $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$. Then $Q = T(1 + T^\ast T)^{-1} = \frac{2}{5}S$, so $\sigma(Q) = \frac{2}{5}D$ where $D$ is the closed unit disk. However, $1 \in 2D = \sigma(T)$, but $f(1) = \frac{1}{2} \notin \frac{2}{5}D = \sigma(Q)$. (In fact, $f(\sigma(T)) = \frac{1}{2}D \supsetneq \frac{2}{5}D = \sigma(Q)$.)

Thank you. This question stems from the intuition behind the proof of the spectral theorem for unbounded operators by mapping them to bounded ones using an appropriate transformation of the complex plane to a bounded subset. The choices $T(1+|T|)^{-1}$ or $T(1+T^*T)^{-1/2}$ might be more natural as they are bijections on their image in the complex case, but proving these operators bounded in general might be difficult. Would you know if there is a way to map unbounded operators to bounded ones with control on the spectra?

@Olius Both $T(1 + |T|)^{-1}$ and $T(1 + T^\ast T)^{-1/2}$ are bounded. That can be proved by spectral theorem. What kind of control on the spectra do you want though…?

I meant to ask whether $T(1+|T|)^{-1}$ or $T(1+T^*T)^{-1/2}$ are bounded for general, unbounded closed densely-defined, non-normal $T$. Are you also referring to this general case when you mention the spectral theorem?

@Olius That is what I meant, yes. The spectral theorem is not applied to $T$, but to $T^\ast T$, which is also closed and densely defined.

I must go now but will think about how to prove that when I come back. In this case the control I was thinking of would be knowing that the spectrum of, say $T(1+|T|)^{-1}$, contains $g(\sigma(T))$ for $g(z) = z/(1+|z|)$, or more generally some function of $\sigma(T)$. In this way one could think of the extra points as some kind of "spectrum at infinity."

Thank goodness $|T|$ is on the right in the polar decomposition of $T$. I had not thought of it interacting with $(1+|T|)^{-1}$, but now that you've said it that was easy. In this case $T = \alpha S$ is no longer a counterexample to $g(\sigma(T)) \subset \sigma(T(1+|T|)^{-1})$; if you think I should ask a new question for this case, or for $T(1+T^*T)^{-1/2}$, I shall.

@Olius I'll let you decide whether to ask a new question. But yeah, $T = \alpha S$ certainly no longer works in this case. Though, while I don't immediately see an example right now, I find it quite unlikely that $g(\sigma(T)) \subset \sigma(T(1+|T|)^{-1})$ will hold in general.
